# How spark get the size of a dataframe for broadcast?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.2

I set this setting : `--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=209715200 //200mb`

And i want to decrease this amount to be just a little higher than a specific dataFrame (Let s call it `bdrDf`)

I tried to esmimate the `bdrDf` :

```scala
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

val bytes = sparkSession.sessionState.executePlan(bdrDf.queryExecution.logical)
.optimizedPlan.stats(sparkSession.sessionState.conf).sizeInBytes

println("bdrDfsize mb:" + FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(bytes.toLong))
```

i got : `58 MB`

Is this the size that Spark will get when it will check if the dataframe is below or not of `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` ?

I also saw this metric of the sparkUI :

[image]

It corresponds to `492 MB`

Is one of my values correct ? if no, how to estimate the size of my dataframe ?

code:

```
val Df= readFromHive()      
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils     

def checkSize(df: DataFrame)(implicit spark: SparkSession) = {       
  df.cache.foreach(el => el)       
  val catalyst_plan = df.queryExecution.logical

 val df_size_in_bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(catalyst_plan).optimizedPlan.stats(sparkSession.sessionState.conf).sizeInBytes

 logger.info("size in mO:" + 
   FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(df_size_in_bytes.toLong))       
 logger.info("size bytes:" + df_size_in_bytes)     

}     

checkSize(Df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this function:

```
  def checkSize(df: DataFrame)(implicit spark: SparkSession) = {
    df.cache.foreach(el => el)
    val catalyst_plan = df.queryExecution.logical
    val df_size_in_bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(
      catalyst_plan).optimizedPlan.statistics.sizeInBytes
    df_size_in_bytes
  }
```

With this method is mandatory to cache the df, and because it is a lazy operation you need to perform the **foreach** action, a little weird ..., check if that works for you

Comment: I used `.stats(sparkSession.sessionState.conf)` instead of `statistics`, maybe its because your code is for version higher of 2.2
So this code will give me the amount that spark will compare with `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` ?

Comment: maybe, it is a little bit old. I had this function in a project running on a 2.2. This code gives the amount of bytes of the dataframe, so you could see of it exceeds the threshold for the broadcast process in join operations.

Comment: i get
size in m:303 MB
size bytes:317808272

Its higher than my spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold (200mb) and my df is broadcasted ...

Comment: can you add the code and an image of the driver console with the stages?

Comment: ```val Df= readFromHive()

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
    def checkSize(df: DataFrame)(implicit spark: SparkSession) = {
      df.cache.foreach(el => el)
      val catalyst_plan = df.queryExecution.logical
      val df_size_in_bytes = spark.sessionState.executePlan(
        catalyst_plan).optimizedPlan.stats(sparkSession.sessionState.conf).sizeInBytes
      logger.info("size in mO:" + FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(df_size_in_bytes.toLong))
      logger.info("size bytes:" + df_size_in_bytes)
    }
    checkSize(Df)
```
I dont know what do you want in the img?

Comment: Besides the call, what spark operation is executing the broadcast.. a join?

Comment: Yes spark is doing a join